# Highly recommended references on Modular Forms

Tags: complex-analysis, riemannian-geometry, dynamical-systems, hyperbolic-geometry, modular-forms

I was reading this following attached below part of the **asymptotic winding of the geodesic flow on modular surfaces and continuous fractions** article, *Y. Guivarc'h* and *Y. Le Jan*.
[image]
[image]
To be honest, I know nothing about **Modular Forms**. Therefore, I would be very grateful if one could suggest highly recommended references on **Modular Forms**. (I am not required to master this area of Mathematics, but to understand, at least, this part of the article).

Comment: You could always choose Diamond's A First Course in Modular Forms (maybe not that elementary).

Comment: Maybe have a look at the first chapter of [The 1-2-3 of modular forms](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-74119-0). Diamond and Shurman is great, but it is definitely not elementary, and is geared towards the specific application of Fermat's Last Theorem.

Comment: @Yourong'DZR'Zang which chapters, in case you can find out?

Comment: @Neilhawking you could see a chapter with the name 'Dimension Formulas'. But judging from your previous questions, I won't expect to understand them in a short period. Assuming the results is therefore an option that's worth considering.

Comment: To be honest, there is **no** elementary references for Modular forms, and especially **not** for the level of the excerpt you asked about in your question which includes Riemann-Roch.

Comment: @Somos it doesn't have to be elementary at all, just highly recommended.

Comment: So, you were reading that article knowing **nothing** about Modular Forms? Please tell us the reason why you were reading it. Did you understand anything at all in the article aside from modular forms?

Comment: @Somos the first part of it is about modular spaces and they are somehow clear

Comment: And is "modular spaces" actually spaces of modular forms? How do they make sense if you know nothing about modular forms?

Comment: @Somos you can take a look at the following link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4053981/some-simple-questions-regarding-modular-spaces-modular-forms-hyperbolic-geomet to see what I meant